# Como obtener el index de una nodelist con evento click?

Tags: javascript, onclicklistener

tengo una nodelist devuelta por un queryselectorall en la variable $nodo, a su vez capturo el click con delegacion usando e.target y filtrando con una clase (clickeable)
como obtengo el indice del $nodo (e.target) al clickear sobre el?

```
<body>
  <div class="clickeable">UNO</div>
  <div class="clickeable">DOS</div>
  <div class="clickeable">TRES</div>

  <script>
    let $nodo = document.querySelectorAll(".clickeable");
    document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
      if(e.target.matches(".clickeable")) alert()
    })
  </script>
  
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

Como convenido, aquí tienes una forma de hacerlo a través del `document`:

```javascript
// tu variable devuelve nodos
const $nodo = document.querySelectorAll(".clickeable");

// convierto tu nodeList en Array para poder acceder a sus métodos
const arrayNodo = [...$nodo];

document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  // separo el target para manejarlo
  const {target} = e;
  
  if(target.matches(".clickeable")) {
    // utilizo el método de búsqueda de index de Array para obtener index
    const index = arrayNodo.findIndex((el) => el === target)

    // imprimo index
    console.log(index)
  }
})
```

La única "magia" es cambiar tu `nodeList` a `Array` para poder acceder a los métodos del prototipo. Si por alguna razón quieres trabajar solo con `nodeList` en tu app, podrías añadir un método `findIndex` al prototipo y así forzar el comportamiento de `nodeList` como un `Array`.

---

Hilo antiguo:

Con un cambio de enfoque:

```javascript
const $nodo = document.querySelectorAll(".clickeable");

// iteras y entregas el índice como argumento
$nodo.forEach((nodo, index) => {

  // asignas a cada instancia de tu lista el evento
  nodo.addEventListener("click", function (e) {

    // aquí manipulas el índice del elemento en el arreglo
    console.log(index);
  });
});
```

El código que te propongo asigna el `addEventListener` a cada nodo en lugar de `document`. Como tienes la lista de objetos almacenada en `$nodo`, puedes perfectamente ejecutar un `forEach` para iterarlos y sobre cada uno crear un `eventListener`.

La magia es que cuando asignes el listener de evento al objeto, incluyes su índice dentro del arreglo como argumento y listo, lo puedes controlar desde adentro.

Comment: Se que se puede hacer de esa manera, pero necesito hacerlo a traves de delegacion de eventos al document. Busque en cada object $nodo pensando que tendria una propiedad index pero no di con ella. Lo he podido solucionar agregando un data attribute igual al num de indice de cada nodo, pero la idea era sacar el dato del propio objeto. Gracias por tu tiempo de todos modos!!

Comment: Respuesta editada en base a tu aclaración. Me comentas.

Comment: Magistral, me guardo la funcion, muchas gracias @Devandmus

Comment: Genial! Gracias por la buena pregunta, seguro ayudará a muchos ;)